# ClassFormatError - Incompatible magic value

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, applet, jsessionid

I try use applet in my web application.

Applet class:

```
public class TestApplet extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Applet!");
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello World");
                    add(lbl);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

In JSP:

```
<applet code="TestApplet.class" width="320" height="120" ></applet>
```

But when I load page after loading applet, I get this error.

```
ClassFormatError - Incompatible magic value 168430090 in class file TestApplet.
```

In my app I use Spring Security - if it's relevant.

Comment: [This](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21518927) might help.

Comment: I saw it, but there is resolving for Weblogic. I use TomCat 7, and i tried convert it to TomCat, but not work. I got again this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this error before when the server sent back an error page or login page instead of the jar/class file. You can use something like [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) to look at what your webserver is actually sending back to your browser, you should be able to see what it's sending back. A lot of appservers now set httpOnly=true on their cookies, and a bug in the java browser plugin means that it doesn't send the jsessionid when requesting jars. Obviously this only really applies if you're using form-based authentication or similar.